# Deploy Django Project On Apache Server with Cpanel

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, cpanel

I am a beginner to web development in python using the `django framework`.
I have created a sample project, it is working well on localhost but now I want to learn how to deploy this on Apache server with Cpanel.
Where should i place my django application code in cPanel.
What changes my django project required.

Need step by step procedure for how to do it.?

Comment: can you make sure your cPanel supports django?

Comment: What is the purpose of cpanel here ..? why you didn't tried heroku or google app engine

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `mod_wsgi` with Apache. Documentation [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Basic steps:

1. Install mod_wsgi. [Instructions](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi) on github project
2. Edit your Apache's `httpd.conf` file. Sample (copied from Django's docs):

   ```
   WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite.com/mysite/wsgi.py
   WSGIPythonPath /path/to/mysite.com

   <Directory /path/to/mysite.com/mysite>
   <Files wsgi.py>
   Require all granted
   </Files>
   </Directory>
   ```

Comment: you don't have make any changes to django project

Comment: will you explain me if i have cpanel then where should i will place my django based application code.

Comment: I really doubt cPanel would support django. Then I am not sure. And may be you could start a new question with exact details about deployment